# hide and unhide system bar on touch in android

Tags: android

Does anybody have any idea about how to hide and unhidden bottom system bar in `android` ?

I got this code for hiding system bar:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

But when I touch anywhere on screen it appears and will not hide it there after. what I want is that when I touch or swipe up system bar shows and else it always shown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: not yet a perfect working solution. In android latest versions, full screen activity something is there which do the requirement. In my case, i have to do the requirement after the project did almost complete. So this solution not works fine

Answer (score 0):

From Android 4.4 you can use immersive mode as described here :

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

This will hide the navigation bar along with the status bar.  A swipe at the bottom or top will bring them back

Comment: i am using android 4.0 to up, is there any code for that ??

Comment: Have you tried using the following theme in your manifest : @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen ?

Answer (score 0):

Once try as follows

It will hide system bar if it is showing else it will show.

```
public void toggleFullscreen() {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);   

}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: it will hide the system bar and when I touch on screen it will show system bar, but how can I hide it again ??

Comment: @Shanu786 If you touch again it will hide.